# Pair two bluetooth devices by clicking on a listView item, Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-bluetooth

I'm relatively new to programming on java for android and can't figure out how to pair two devices by clicking on an item of a listView that contains a list of newly discovered devices.

I've already created a listView containing a set of newly discovered devices and here is a part of my code for a click event:`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView newListView; // listView containing newly discovered devices
ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    /* Variables definition */

    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    newListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_lv);

    // New Devices List View item click
    newListView.setClickable(true);

    newListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // some code must go here, but I can't figure out which one 


        }
    });

   }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Where is the list of Bluetooth devices? This code just has an empty adapter, as far as you've shown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect the Bluetooth device by click the item of listview in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132160/how-to-connect-the-bluetooth-device-by-click-the-item-of-listview-in-android)

Comment: the list of discovered Bluetooth devices is stored in a "newListView" but I can't figure out how to create an instance of a BluetoothDevice in order to pair this newly discovered device (which I choose by clicking on an item from a newListView) with my BluetoothAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of strings, yes, in the adapter?

You can get a `BluetoothDevice` object from the [`BluetoothAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String))

```
newListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String address = mDevicesAdatper.getItem(position);
        BluetoothDevice btDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        // TODO: Pair

    }
});
```

Much of the specifics for handling paired devices is in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: String address = mDevicesAdatper.get(position); worked for me in android studio 3.3

Comment: @SurendraMeena `ArrayAdapter` has no `get(int)` method

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, You're right, I was using arrayList instead of arrayAdapter to get the address. Can you Please look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438660/bluetooth-socket-not-connecting-unable-to-pair-devices