# Bluetooth socket not connecting, Unable to pair devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm learning android and working on an project's app which uses Bluetooth.  I was already able to discover and list devices. But when I try to pair devices, socket.connect() fails everytime. I'm new to java and android.

I have tried an insecure connection, default UUID and device's UUID but still got the same result and logs.

here is the complete code so far

```
package com.example.bluetoothhc;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import static com.example.bluetoothhc.R.id.listView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  BluetoothSocket socket;
    private  BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID DEFAULT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    ListView listView;
    TextView statusView;
    Button searchButton;
    ArrayList<String> bluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    //defining a common tag
    private final static String TAG = "Main Activity";
    //BT adapter is one for the entire system so define it globally

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdaptera;


    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.i("Action2",action);
            if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                statusView.setText("Finished");
                searchButton.setEnabled(true);
                Log.i("Action3","df");
            }
            else if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                Log.i("Action34","dfsff");
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String name = device.getName();
                String Address = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                //distance between deivce or signal strength, more negative favourable
                //String rssi = Integer.toString(intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE));
                Log.i("device found","Name: "+ name +"Address: " + Address );
//                String deviceInfo = "";
//                if(name== null || name.equals("")){
//                    deviceInfo += Address;
//                }
//                else{
//                    deviceInfo += name ;
//                }
                String deviceInfo=Address;
                if(!bluetoothDevices.contains(deviceInfo)) {
                    bluetoothDevices.add(deviceInfo);
                }
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    };


    public void SearchClicked(View view){
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        statusView.setText("Searching...");
        searchButton.setEnabled(false);
        Log.i("info - searchClicked","search button Disabled");
        int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if(bluetoothAdaptera.isDiscovering()){
            bluetoothAdaptera.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i("SearchCliced","Canceling discovery");
        }
        Log.i("SearchCliced","Starting Discovering");
        bluetoothAdaptera.startDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //assing UI Components
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        statusView = findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);
        searchButton = findViewById(R.id.SearchButtonView);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,bluetoothDevices);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //getting the BT adapter
        bluetoothAdaptera = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // check if bluetooth adapter is present in the device
        if(bluetoothAdaptera == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device doesn't support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        //check if BT is enabled
        if(!bluetoothAdaptera.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBTIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
// WE NEED TO CREATE ANOTHER LIST FOR PAIRED DEVICES FOR ONLCIK EVENTS FUNCTION
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdaptera.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                Log.i("device",""+deviceName +" "+deviceHardwareAddress);
                if(deviceName== null || deviceName.equals("")){
                    bluetoothDevices.add(deviceHardwareAddress );
                }
                else{
                    bluetoothDevices.add(deviceHardwareAddress );

                    //  bluetoothDevices.add(deviceName );
                }
            }
        }



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("clickList1","itemclicked");


            String address = bluetoothDevices.get(position);
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdaptera.getRemoteDevice(address);
            Log.i("BTDevice C Name", device.getAddress());
            Log.d(TAG, address);

            BluetoothSocket tmp=null;

            bluetoothAdaptera.cancelDiscovery();
            mmDevice = device;
            try {
                // Use the UUID of the device that discovered //
                if (mmDevice != null)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Device Name1: " + mmDevice.getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Device UUID1: " + mmDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( mmDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
//                    createMethod = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
//                    tmp = (BluetoothSocket)createMethod.invoke(device, 1);

                    // tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mmDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                    Log.i("DEvice UUID","socket created successfully with device uuid");
                }
                else Log.d(TAG, "Device is null.");
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, " UUID from device is null, Using Default UUID, Device name: " + device.getName());
                try {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(DEFAULT_UUID);
                    Log.i("default UUID","socket created successfully with default uuid");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("IOEX","printStack");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("IOException","2");
            }

            socket = tmp;

            try {
                Log.i(TAG,"Trying to connect");
                // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
                socket.connect();
                Log.i(TAG,"connection_successful");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    Log.i(TAG,"connection failed - socket closed");
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Don't forget to unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

[image: logs]

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create BluetoothServerSocket with this method listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord() with the use of BluetoothAdapter:

```
BluetoothServerSocket mServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
```

then you can create

```
BluetoothSocket socket = mServerSocket.accept();
```

and then use

```
socket.connect();
```

After connecting with this method you have to do as below:

```
BluetoothDevice device = socket.getRemoteDevice();
BluetoothSocket tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(DEVICE_UUID);
tmp.connect();
```

So let me clear you that you are using createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() method directly and try to connect socket but instead of that try this way. i hope it will clear your doubts now.

But please remember that, listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord() is long background process method so take care it with thread or async task. hope it helps. thanks!!

Comment: I'm making the app to connect to Arduino through hc-05 module. So, in that case, the module is server side and my app is the client. so, when it is not going to accept any incoming connection, should I still have to use BluetoothServerSocket?

Comment: hi, i have just edited my answer to clear your doubts. i have connected with "Polar H7" device with this way. so it may helps you.